# Casting to a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm writing a command processing module and I'm having issues casting a class implementing the interface to its generic interface definition. The isolated code in question:

```
public class Program
{
    public interface ICommand
    {
    }

    public class TestCommand : ICommand
    {
        public int Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ICommandHandler<T> where T : ICommand
    {
        void Process(T command);
    }

    public class TestCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<TestCommand>
    {
        public void Process(TestCommand command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(command.Foo);
        }
    }

    public class CommandHandlersBindings
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> commandHandlers;

        public CommandHandlersBindings()
        {
            commandHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        }

        public ICommandHandler<T> GetCommandHandler<T>(T command) where T : ICommand
        {
            return (ICommandHandler<T>) commandHandlers[command.GetType()];
        }

        public void RegisterCommandHandler<T>(ICommandHandler<T> handler) where T : ICommand
        {
            commandHandlers[typeof(T)] = handler;
        }
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        var commandBindings = new CommandHandlersBindings();
        commandBindings.RegisterCommandHandler(new TestCommandHandler());

        ICommand command = new TestCommand();
        var handler = commandBindings.GetCommandHandler(command);

        handler.Process(command);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The issue is in the function GetCommandHandler which throws

> System.InvalidCastException saying that it's unable to cast object of type 'TestCommandHandler' to type 'ICommandHandler`1[ICommand]'.

At runtime I'll only know that the received commands are ICommands and I'd love my dictionary to be able to handle that.

Comment: Just because `TestCommand` is-a `ICommand` it doesn't mean that `ICommandHandler<TestCommand>` is-a `ICommandHandler<ICommand>` - it is **not**.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer on the duplicate. It's an excellent discussion on why you can't do this particular cast.

Comment: Interesting. Is there any way of explicitly forcing that cast/conversion? A covariant interface isn't a solution in my case.

Comment: The best thing you can do is create `public interface ICommandHandler { void Process(ICommand command); }` and then change `ICommandHandler<T>` to `public interface ICommandHandler<T> : ICommandHandler where T : ICommand`. Then it's just a matter of implementing `ICommandHandler` explicitly in `TestCommandHandler` and doing a run-time type check before calling `this.Process((TestCommand)command);`.